# Functional way to generate file names in Scala

Tags: scala, random, functional-programming

Ok, I want to generate temp file names. So, I created a class with var `tempFileName` and `fileNo` such that it creates files like

```
BSirCN_0.txt
BSirCN_1.txt
BSirCN_2.txt
```

But, to do this I have to keep count and the way I am going it is calling `next()` function of the class which returns the filename in sequence (should return `BSirCN_4` in the above case. Now this goes against FP as I am modifying the state i.e. the count of names in the Object. How do I do it in a functional way. One way I can think of is keeping count where the function is called and just concatenate. Any other ways?

Comment: How often do you need a new filename?  How long will each temporary file be needed?  Concatenate your prefix, `BSirCN_` with an appropriate slice of the current date/time from the system clock.

Comment: This is an ambiguous  question.  *Pure* functional programming treats computation as evaluation of mathematical functions that avoids mutable data. Functional code is idempotent: a function's return value depends only on its arguments. This is in contrast to imperative programming where, generally speaking, program state allows side effects. Why to mix *pure* FP with stateful classes?

Answer (score 6):

Just return a new object:

```
case class FileGenerator(tempFileName: String, fileNo: Long = 0) {
  lazy val currentFileName = tempFileName + "_" + fileNo
  lazy val next = FileGenerator(tempFileName, fileNo + 1)
}
```

You can then do:

```
val generator = FileGenerator("BSirCN")

val first = generator.currentFileName
val next = generator.next.currentFileName
```

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid the mutations using an **Iterator** *(or any other kind of infinite & lazy collection)*.

```
final class TempFileNamesGenerator(prefix: String) {
  private[this] val generator =
    Iterator
      .from(start = 0)
      .map(i => s"${prefix}_${i}.txt")

  def next(): String =
    generator.next()
}

val generator = new TempFileNamesGenerator(prefix = "BSirCN")

generator.next() // BSirCN_0.txt
generator.next() // BSirCN_1.txt
generator.next() // BSirCN_2.txt
```

Comment: Iterators are still mutable. Streams would be better.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon well yes, but still better than having vars IMHO. Anyways, yes. If a full immutable solution is wanted then Jean answers would be the best, but if one needs too many temp file, it can become quite difficult to handle.

Answer (score 4):

A similar solution to one proposed by @Luis but using streams:

```
def namesStream(prefix: String, suffix: String): Stream[String] = Stream.from(0).map(n => s"$prefix$n$suffix")
```

Then use it like this:

```
val stream = namesStream("BSirCN_", ".txt")
stream.take(5) // BSirCN_1.txt, BSirCN_2.txt, BSirCN_3.txt, BSirCN_4.txt, BSirCN_5.txt
// or
stream.drop(10).take(2) // BSirCN_11.txt, BSirCN_12.txt
```